# How index helps for join in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, indexing, sql-server-2012

I'm newbie to SQL Server. I'm not clear about how an index helps for join in SQL Server. When we join two tables, how does the index took place, in which manner it executes the query? Is there any links to read out to understand this?

I understand how the where clause works, by the this  [VIDEO](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p9FlnOPltA8)..

Is there any other video or article link to understand about join vs index

Comment: Have you ever heard of google? Not sure why people run to stack overflow. I don't know how to put on my pants. Can somebody help me? MSSQL have a whole MSDN site to help you figure this out.

Comment: @Jaques: finding the *relevant* articles in MSDN is far from trivial, and a newbie will have to be clairvoyant to come up with the right google search to land on the relevant article. Pointing him to the right articles is much better than asking him to search on its own.

Comment: Then there are - cough - books. SQL for Dummies in this case. But hey, today kids do not want to use their brain. Just give me all knowledge prepared so I dont have to think. Nice attitude.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are three ways to do a join:

1. Nested Loops

With nested loops one side of the join is scanned, and the other side is probed (key is seek-ed). The probe can get a  huge boost if there is an index to leverage. See [Understanding Nested Loops Joins](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191318(v=sql.105).aspx)

2. Hash Join

Hash scan one side of the join, build a [hash table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table) in memory, and the scan the other side and match the keys in the hash table. No index benefits hash joins. See [Understanding Hash Joins](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189313(v=sql.105).aspx).

3. Merge Join

Merge join require both sides to be sorted. They work by iterating both side simultaneously and rely on the sort order guarantee to decide if the keys match, w/o a need to look ahead or keep state. To offer the sort guarantee, an index may be leveraged. See [Understanding Merge Joins](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190967(v=sql.105).aspx).

I recommend you read [Understanding how SQL Server executes a query](http://rusanu.com/2013/08/01/understanding-how-sql-server-executes-a-query/) and [How to analyse SQL Server performance](http://rusanu.com/2014/02/24/how-to-analyse-sql-server-performance/). In general you should design your data model and queries in a way that the filtering occurs before the joins. If you need to join big datasets indexes may help, but the battle is already lost.

Answer (score 0):

You have to read at least 1 book before looking for Video!

With the index, the server can find the corresponding rows much faster than scanning all records (in case when table has many rows and result is few of them). For example, if the table has 10,000,000 rows and the query has to return 20 rows - with index the server may read average ~20 MB of data (50% of 10M * 32bit index) instead of 1500 MB (50% of e.g. 10M rows * 300 bytes).